# how to hide the master page content in a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, sitemap

I want to open a regular .aspx page in a rad window.But the regular page consists of Site Map.I don't want that sitemap to be displayed when it is opened in rad window.
Please suggest me some solution.

I already tried this:
this.MasterpageFile="..//test.Master";
But in my page it does not work

Comment: i think in code behind it is possible to do

Answer (score 0):

So you will have ContentPlaceHolders which will automatically inherit from the master page. If you go to the regular .aspx page and head into Design view you will see sections with all the content from the Master Page.
If you click the little right arrow to the right of the area that looks like a Div, you should be able to change the content back to what you have in your regular aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a public property on `MasterPage` to show hide your site map , on your rad window page access that Property and make it hide.

```
public bool MyProperty()
{
// get and set your controls visibility
}
```

Access your property like `this.Master.MyProperty = false`